# Drupal how to rebuild à form without hook_form_alter

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I need to rebuild a form after another form submit (this form gives me the values I need for the second one), the two forms are in the same page so the hook_form_alter can only be called at the building of the page.

I try to add an Ajax callback on my second form to rebuild it but doesnt work, I also try a ajax_command_replace but doesnt work too.

I really don't know what to do now, do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

**1:  Form1 submit -> redirect to same page -> PHP get the form value -> Put value in form2 use form_alter**

**2:  Form1 submit -> Ajax change form2 value.** You may need merge them into a same form ID

Example module provide all coding about form Ajax, like "Add more" button

https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

[image]

After install example module, enable ajax_example, visit path **examples/ajax_example/dependent_dropdown_degrades_no_js**
In the ajax_example you'll have all coding help fix your issue. Try read it.  :)

```
    $items['examples/ajax_example/dependent_dropdown_degrades_no_js'] = array(
    'title' => 'Dependent dropdown with javascript off',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_degrades', TRUE),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file' => 'ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc',
    'weight' => 5,   );
```

Comment: I try to make the second one, I try to use the ajax_command_replace that should replace the form html by another html but when I use it it doesn't replace anything, I also hear that when you put an ajax callback to a form field when the callback is called the form is automatically rebuild, but I don't have this behavior too

Comment: Also in the module file hook menu function, it has many different type of ajax. You may find what you want.

Comment: I look at the example but they provide solution to repopulate a select / change a field, for my form I need to rebuild the form (because I need to create fields in function of a number choose on the first form) or at least relaunch the form_alter of my second form because it's in this hook_form_alter that I've created the new fields dependant of the first form